# Blender to unity, object rotated

Tags: export

I'm working on a video game project with a friend. I use blender and he uses Unity, but we have a problem trying to make a very simple object, a stone.

We made a first stone elongated on the x-axis that seems to work, then another elongated on the z-axis. This one doesn't work well and arrives lying on unity. I tried to apply a -90° rotation on the X axis and it didn't work.

What can I do?

Comment: What format do you use to export ?

Comment: fbx ! But we found out. I just need to -90° on x, apply, the put 90°.